# What does $e^{i \pi \mathbf x} \in \mathbb C^2$ mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, coding-theory

I saw this in an book (coding theory) without explanation and I need help figuring out the meaning.

> Consider $\mathbf x\in \{0,1\}^2$ and
> $$
> \mathbf s = e^{i \pi \mathbf x} \in \mathbb C^2 \tag 1
> $$

I know $\{0,1\}^2$ and $\mathbb C^2$ are the cartesian products, i.e.
\begin{align}
\{0,1\}^2&=\{0,1\}\times \{0,1\}\\
&=\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)\} \tag 2
\\
\mathbb C^2 &=\mathbb C \times \mathbb C = \{(z,y): z,y\in \mathbb C\} \tag 3
\end{align}
So $\mathbf x= (x_1,x_2)$ is a vector which take a value in the set $\{0,1\}^2$, for instance, $\mathbf x = (1,1)$.

So far so good, but what is $e^{i \pi \mathbf x} \in \mathbb C^2$?
Any examples?

Say $\mathbf x = (1,1)$, what does $e^{i \pi (1,1)} \in \mathbb C^2$ mean?

Any clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess it means $e^{i\pi(x,y)}=\left(e^{i\pi x}, e^{i\pi y}\right)$

Comment: @saulspatz is correct. It is a violation of mathematical notation.

Comment: @Hermis14 Never seen, is this notation common in coding theory? It doesn't look good... quite counter-intuitive.

Comment: @Donsert I don't know much about coding theory, but at least, if you learn MATLAB (programming language) for instance, you will find that a pretty large number of built-in functions support the weird notation. For instance, we will get exp([0 1]) = [1 2.718].

Comment: God, that notation is abysmal, especially since it's given without explanation. Good answer, @saulspatz . Note to OP: don't confuse this with the [matrix exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential) !

Comment: @Donsert No, this notation is definitely not common in (mathematical approaches to) coding theory. I don't know what the computer scientists might be doing here.

Answer (score 3):

In general you can without comment extend any function $f: A \to B$ to a function of the same name $f: A^n \to B^n$ by defining $f(a_1, a_2, ..., a_n) = (f(a_1), f(a_2), ... f(a_n)).$

In your particular case, $A = \left\{0, 1\right\}$, $B = \mathbb{C}$, $f(a) = e^{i \pi a}$, and $n = 2$.

So $e^{i \pi (x_1, x_2)} = (e^{i \pi x_1}, e^{i \pi x_2})$.

A simpler way to write exactly the same transformation is $f(x) = (-1)^x$. Basically the idea is to send all the $0$ bits to $1$ and send all the $1$ bits to $-1$.

Comment: Interesting, if I see $f:A^n \rightarrow B^n$ I think of a vector-valued function, for instance $f:\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ so $f(x_1,x_2)=(f_1(x_1,x_2),f_2(x_1,x_2))$.
I have never seen $f(a_1, a_2, \dots , a_n) = (f(a_1), f(a_2), \dots, f(a_n))$ for $f:A^n \rightarrow B^n$. Is this something specific for coding theory?

Comment: No, it's a general mathematical convention.

ALMOST ALL functions $f : A^n \to B^n$ do not decompose this way. For example, $g(x, y) = (x + y, xy)$ does not decompose. But $h : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2 = (x e^{3x}, y e^{3y})$ can be taken as the extension of $h : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} = x e^{3x}$ where the two functions $h: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $h:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ have the same name and work basically the same way even though their domains and ranges are different.

Comment: "A less grandiose way...."  Not quite. The mapping is _not_ $f(x)=2x-1$ bur rather $f(x) = (-1)^x$ which sends $0$'s to $+1$ and $1$'s to $-1$.

Comment: You have $n$ in $B^n$, doesn't it mean the function has $n$ components, i.e. $f(a_1, a_2,\dots , a_n) = (f_1(a_1), f_2(a_2), \dots, f_n(a_n))$, where each $f_i:A \rightarrow B$?

Comment: @DilipSarwate - thanks, fixed to 1 - 2x

Comment: @Donsert - yes, that's correct, and all of the $f_i$ are identical to each other

Comment: Agree with the explanation (+1). Just want to add the point that $e^{\pi i x}$ is more logical than $1-2x$ **as a mapping from $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ to $\Bbb{C}$**. True, when restricted to the subset $\{0,1\}$ of the reals they agree. But $e^{i\pi x}$ (or $(-1)^x$) gives **a homomorphism** from $(\Bbb{Z},+)$ to $(\Bbb{C}^*,\cdot)$ **and** yields a *well defined* homomorphism from $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ also. But nobody would see $x\mapsto 1-2x$ as a homomorphism! This becomes second nature after you have worked with additive characters of finite fields for a while :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen changed $1 - 2x$ to $(-1)^x$

Answer (score -1):

$e^{0} = 1$ and $e^{i\pi} = -1$ implying for example $e^{i \pi (1,1)} = e^{ (i \pi,i \pi)} = (-1,-1)$

so if $\mathbf x \in \{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)\}=\{0,1\}^2$

then $e^{i \pi \mathbf x} \in \{(1,1),(1,-1),(-1,1),(-1,-1)\} = \{1,-1\}^2 \subset \mathbb C^2$ and $e^{i \pi \mathbf x} \in \mathbb C^2$